# Ampersand to run process in background causes invalid parameters in Bash 5

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that runs perfectly well on Bash 3.2. The script contains an ampersand to run a process in the background. However, when I run it in Bash 5.x, it doesn't pass the variables correctly (I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"). When I take off the ampersand at the end (of the mgeneratejs line), it executes normally in Bash 5.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Works on Bash 3.2 on MacOS

#Doesn't work in bash-5.0/5.1
##!/usr/bin/env bash

NUM_ROWS_PER_RUN=5
NUM_RUNS=2
TEMPLATE_STRING='{
        name: "$name"
        }'

for i in $(seq 1 "$NUM_RUNS")
do
    echo "Starting run ${i}"

    #If you dont have it, then run "npm install -g mgeneratejs"
    mgeneratejs -n "$NUM_ROWS_PER_RUN" "${TEMPLATE_STRING//[$'\r\n ']}" &
done
echo "Waiting"
wait
echo "Finished"
```

How can I get the process (mgeneratejs) to run in the background when using Bash 5.x?

Comment: hey, did you solve the problem? did my answer help?

Comment: @JuanR Thank you! I made the changes to the script from your answer and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash may or may not be in fault here, but be sure that the problema is in `mgeneratejs`.

Taking a look `mgeneratejs`'s source code I found this:

```
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
  var str = argv._[0];
  template = _.startsWith(str, '{') ? parseTemplate(str) : parseTemplate(read(str, 'utf8'));
  generate();
} else {
  template = '';
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
  process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
    var chunk = process.stdin.read();
    if (chunk !== null) {
      template += chunk;
    } 
  });
  process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    template = JSON.parse(template); 
    generate();
  });
}
```

If `stdin` is not a TTY then `mgeneratejs` assumes that `stdin` is a pipe, and tries to read from it. This is wrong, they should at least check if the template has been given in the command line args.

I would't recommend that you fix `mgeneratejs`, but I can recommend you to do this:

```
function do_run() {
    echo "${TEMPLATE_STRING//[$'\r\n ']}" | mgeneratejs -n "$NUM_ROWS_PER_RUN"
}

for i in $(seq 1 "$NUM_RUNS")
do
    echo "Starting run ${i}"

    #If you dont have it, then run "npm install -g mgeneratejs"
    do_run &
done
```